# how to share files and folder between 2 computers in WAN

Tags: networking, network-manager, 17.10

I want to share my data with a friend that he live in another city so we can't build a LAN connection can we make it with WAN??

Comment: As long as you can find each other (IP) via internet you can just use Samba. If not you could use a VPN-tunnel

Comment: Cloud storage services such as Dropbox, Mega, etc. make it really easy to share data (files/folders) privately. There's no need to use elaborate setups now. You can, of course, do as mentioned above. However, if you want help with specifics you have to be specific yourself in the question.